# Excel VBA Worksheet Change Monitoring

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet-function

I have an excel sheet that should behave a specific way.

For example the cells I11 - I20 are user input cells in the form of a drop down.

For these cells I need to monitor if a user selects a value that is less than the number 900.

If a user selects a number less than 900 for cell I11 for example, I need to set cells K11 formula to = J11.

If a user selects a number greater than 900, then i clear the formula and allow the cell to be user input.

I need to do this for all cells that range from I11-I20.

Here is what i have for one cell, however i get an error that states "Object variable or With block variable not set" and this only allows me to change one row.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim A As Range
    Set A = Range("I11")
    If Intersect(Target, A) > 900 Then A.Offset(0, 2).Value = ""
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        A.Offset(0, 2).Value = "=J11"
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Thank you for any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("I11:I20")) Is Nothing Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
                If Target > 900 Then
                    Target.Offset(0, 2).ClearContents
                Else
                    Target.Offset(0, 2).Formula = "=J" & Target.Row
                End If
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This is close to what i am looking for, but this will always set the formula to =J11 , but if i change the target number for cell i15, i should set the formula of k15 = j15.

Comment: Same is true if i change the target value of i13 it should set the value of k13 = j13 etc

Comment: @bars201807302 Sorry about that. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

You have already indicated the target.range, enable events would not be required.
You would not require the formula, just make the cell equal the other cell.

So if there is a change in Column I
And the value is >900, blank the cell 2 columns over. If the change is <=900 then make the cell two columns over equal to the cell 1 column over.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub    ' this stops code error if more than one cell is changed at once

    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("I1:I100")) Is Nothing Then    ' indicates the Target range
        If Target > 900 Then
            Target.Offset(, 2) = ""
        Else: Target.Offset(, 2).Value = Target.Offset(, 1).Value
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```