# Update Date Column of Row in Master Directory Sheet when Item is Selected

Tags: excel

Sheet 1 - Master Records

Sheet 2 - Scheduler

When a record is selected from a Dropdown within Sheet 2 (Scheduler), based on the records in Sheet 1 (Master), I'd like to update a "Last Used" column for that record in Sheet 1 (Master).

I've searched around and haven't quite found out how this can be accomplished... but I'm certain it can be. Example:

Sheet 1 - Master Records

```
**Fullname**, **Last Used**
John Doe, 10/26/2019
Jane Doe, 09/14/2019
Jack Doe, 09/07/2019
Jeni Doe, 07/22/2019
```

Sheet 2 - Scheduler

```
**Assignment**, *Assignment Date*, **Employee**
Cleaner 1, 10/22/2019, John Doe
Cleaner 2, 10/22/2019, Jack Doe
Cleaner 3, 10/16/2019, Jack Doe
Cleaner 4, 10/16/2019, Jeni Doe
```

So as assignments are made, the employee selected for a particular assignment date has their record in the Master Records sheet updated to that assignment date in Sheet 2. I hope this make sense enough...

Comment: There might be a more creative way, but I'd probably just add vba to detect a workbook_change event and add today() when the range intersects. An example of that type of implementation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50630813/2727437)

Comment: Can you explicitly define how the selection in "When a record is selected from a Dropdown within Sheet 2" was done? which cell value will change/effected when a selection was made?